# n(logn) Algorithms problems

Tags: sorting, time-complexity

So I was just finishing up reading on time complexity, and I ran into a few questions that I can't solve.
"You’re given an array of n integers, and must answer a series of n
queries, each of the form: “how many elements of the array have value between
L and R?”, where L and R are integers. Design an O(n log n) algorithm that
answers all of these queries."

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [segment-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree).
2. Or a balanced tree such that [avl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) and store in each node its left and right children. In each query find the `L` and `R` in `O(logn)` and calculate the mid-renge nodes. Construction takes `O(n logn)`. Also for `n` queries you reach `O(n logn)`.
3. Or a [BIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree) with a approach same as second idea.